# Bound on Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a matrix with real entries, $1 \leq i, j, \leq n$. Let $A^{T}=(a_{ij}^{T})$ be the transposed matrix, that is $a_{ij}^{T}=a_{ji}$. Suppose that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$, namely $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Is it true that the operator norm (or another norm) of $A$, $$||A||_{OP}= \sup \{||Af|| : ||f||=1\}$$ is less than or equal to $$\sup_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|.$$ I am asking to either prove or disprove the claim that $$||A||_{OP} \leq \sup_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|$$ for any symmetric matrix $A$.

Comment: If you let $X_1,...,x_n$ be coordinates of $f$ did you try applying Lagrange to find the max of $||Af||$

Comment: @Leader47 I had not tried that, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is real symmetric and $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm, then $\|A\|_{\mathrm{OP}}$ is equal to the spectral radius of $A$. Since $\max_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|$ is the operator norm of $A$ associated with the vector $\infty$-norm and every matrix norm of $A$ consistent with a certain vector norm represents an upper bound on the spectral radius of $A$, the result follows.

It hence remains to show that $\|A\|_{\mathrm{OP}}=\rho(A)$ if $A^T=A$, which is easy if you use the characterization of $\|A\|_{\mathrm{OP}}$ in terms of the spectral radius of $A^TA$ (which follows from its definition and the variational characterization of eigenvalues): $\|A\|_{\mathrm{OP}}=\rho(A^TA)^{1/2}=\rho(A^2)^{1/2}=[\rho(A)^2]^{1/2}=\rho(A)$ (note that $\rho(A^2)=\rho(A)^2$ follows simply from the fact that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are squares of the eigenvalues of $A$).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but in the case of the $\ell^1$-operator norm, the statement is true: if we let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the standard basis, and writing $f=\sum_{i=1} c_ie_i$, by the triangle inequality we have
\begin{align*}
\|Af\|&=\|\sum_{i=1}^n c_iAe_i\| \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|\|Ae_i\| \\
&\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|\right)\max_i\|Ae_i\| \\
&= \|f\|\max_i\|Ae_i\| \\
&\leq \|f\|\max_i\|A^Te_i\| \\
&\leq \|f\|\max_i\sum_j |a_{ij}|\\
\end{align*}
The result is certainly not true for all martix norms. For example, given any matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$, any scalar multiple $\alpha\|\cdot\|$ with $\alpha>1$ is also a matrix norm, and if $\alpha$ is chosen large enough the result will not satisfy the inequality.